# Replace a pattern of elemts in a list Haskell

Tags: haskell

(I'm a complete newbie to stackoverflow, will do my best to ask my question appropiatly, feel free to probe me if I don't).

So, I'm new to Haskell and I'm doing some exercises to get the hang of it.

I've solved half of a exercise which is to replace every occurance of a consonant in a string with that consonant + 'o' + that consonant, then return the new string, here's the code:

```
hurdyGurdy c = concat [ if n `elem` "AEOUYaeouy" then [n] else [n, 'o', n] | n <- c]
```

Although I'm completely stuck at turning hurdyGurdy string back into it's corresponding normal word, ie "HoHelollolo" should become "Hello".

So I'm thinking that I know that every consonant will have a next character 'o', and if I can just delete/drop these out of the list, it's all hunky dory. Or if I replace the whole [n, 'o', n] with n. Although I just don't know how to go about this.

I'm guessing the first way would be simplest, but how do I get rid of the current element AND the next one?

This isn't exactly homework, it's warm up to homework..!

Edit: I've solved it like this.. not exactly nice to look at thou

```
unRovarsprak ("") = ("")
unRovarsprak (c1:'o':c2:xs)
       | isConsonant c1 = c1 : unRovarsprak xs
   | otherwise   = xs
unRovarsprak (c1:xs) 
   | c1 `elem` vokaler = c1 : unRovarsprak xs
   | otherwise      = xs
```

Comment: `Hohelollolo` or `HoHelollolo`?

Comment: Okay so second one, HoHelollolo, just edited!

Comment: Good job on solving it! In the code you pasted, note that the parenthesses aren't necessary around `""` (either as argument or return value).  Then I'm not quite sure what the role of the last line is, but that might by out of bounds to the question you asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a basis of the sort:

```
unHurdyGurdy (c1:'o':c2:xs)
  | isConsonnant c1 && c2 == c1 = c1 : unHurdyGurdy xs
```

This leaves as an exercise for the reader:

- writing `isConsonnant`
- handling vowels
- handling pattern matching failures (strings that aren't the result of `hurdyGurdy`)

Comment: So I'm guessing I can replace isConsonant with c1 `notElem` Vowel, will give this a go! Cheers!